# Mysql select where not evaluate to false

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to find an answer to my question probably because I cannot formulate it correctly so asking here is my last option. I need to select a row which has a certain column any value that does not evaluate to false. Let me give some examples because I am having a hard time explaining this..

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE bool(column)!=false`

should match every row where the value of col is not

```
'0' (string)
''  (string)
0   (integer)
NULL
```

Comment: you want select all of those '0' , '',0, and null ?

Comment: @echo_ME select everything except those

Answer (score 1):

This seems trivial but i may have not understand your question

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE column <> '0' and column <> '' and column <> 0 and column is not null`

Now please tell me why you end up with such a mess. A column can either be integer or text, never both. SQL is not PHP!

Comment: That's exactly what I aim at but isn't there a better way? Something like eval() ? I am not really good with mysql..

Comment: which type is your column?

Comment: I'm building an universal algorithm that will work with all field types. It's a part of a form validation class which will check if a field is ultimately empty or not regardless of the type of the field

Comment: if its universal , why dont you insert them in database all same , if its '' then insert 0 if its '0' then insert 0 if its null then insert 0 and then you can select this column with only one condition and you will have just 0 in this column

Comment: @echo_Me Because I can't ensure that all fields that are to be validated using this rule will be numeric. Even if I could that is a restriction I'd like to avoid having

Comment: You don't understand. a database column can't be universal. it's either numeric or text.

Comment: It's not a single column, any column in any table can be validated with this rule..

Comment: @php_nub_qq then sql is not the way to go.

Comment: Oh my god can you please delete this answer so I can remove the whole question....